# Look Up List of Hostvars for Each Host in Inventory

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I am trying to find a way of creating the following result with the Ansible debug module.

**Desired Results**

```
{
  "myserver01": {
    "host_var_one": "foo",
    "host_var_two": "bar"
  },
  "myserver02": {
    "host_var_one": "biz",
    "host_var_two": "baz"
  },
  "myserver03": {
    "host_var_one": "fizz",
    "host_var_two": "buzz"
  }
}
```

**Example Inventory**

```
[my_servers]
myserver01 host_var_one=foo host_var_two=bar
myserver02 host_var_one=biz host_var_two=baz
myserver03 host_var_one=fizz host_var_two=buzz
```

I would like to be able to provide a list of hostvars and have them displayed in a dict under each host in the inventory, where the key is the hostvar name, and the value is the hostvar value. Including another hostvar in the results should ideally just require adding another variable name to a list.

For example, in the task I would list that I want `["host_var_one", "host_var_two"]` for each host in the inventory and get the above desired results.

I have the following task that gets *somewhat* close to what I want. I just can't figure out a way of listing all desired variables that I want for each host in the format described above. The following only works with one variable, and it doesn't list the variable name along with the value.

**myplaybook.yml**

```
---
- name: Test
  hosts: all
  gather_facts: yes
  user: ansible
  become: yes

  tasks:
    - name: Debug
      debug:
        msg: "{{ dict(query('inventory_hostnames', 'all') | zip(query('inventory_hostnames', 'all') | map('extract', hostvars, 'host_var_one'))) }}"
      run_once: yes
```

**Results of myplaybook.yml**

```
$ ansible-playbook -i inventory test.yml --limit "myserver01"
PLAY [Test] **************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] ***************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [myserver01]

TASK [Debug] *************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [myserver01] => {
    "msg": {
        "myserver01": "foo",
        "myserver02": "biz",
        "myserver03": "fizz"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My solution is as follows:

```yaml
- name: Dict of host_vars
  debug:
    msg: "{{ dict( keys | zip(values) ) }}"
  vars:
    keys: "{{ hostvars | dict2items | map(attribute='key') }}"
    values: "{{ hostvars | dict2items | map(attribute='value') | map('dict2items')
      | map('selectattr', 'key', 'match', 'host_var_') | map('items2dict') }}"
  run_once: yes
```

The result looks like:

```
TASK [Host vars dict] **************************************************
ok: [myserver01] => {
    "msg": {
        "myserver01": {
            "host_var_one": "foo",
            "host_var_two": "bar"
        },
        "myserver02": {
            "host_var_one": "biz",
            "host_var_two": "baz"
        },
        "myserver03": {
            "host_var_one": "fizz",
            "host_var_two": "buzz"
        }
    }
}
```

#### Step by step explanation

Two separate lists are created: `keys` and `values`.

The list for the `keys` is created by converting the dict with `dict2items`, so that the attribute `key` can be extracted by `map`. This way you get the list:

```json
[ "myserver01", "myserver02", "myserver03" ]
```

For the `values` it works the same way, that a list of the `value` attributes is generated. These lists are in each case dicts and must be converted therefore by `map('dict2items')` again into a list. Now the `key` can be filtered over the list via `selectattr`. Here `host_var_` is filtered out by `match` (the beginning of a string). Afterwards the result (list in list) must be converted by `map('items2dict')` back into a dict.

```json
[
  {
    "host_var_one": "foo",
    "host_var_two": "bar"
  },
  {
    "host_var_one": "biz",
    "host_var_two": "baz"
  },
  {
    "host_var_one": "fizz",
    "host_var_two": "buzz"
  }
]
```

Finally, the two lists are merged via `zip` and converted back into one via `dict`.

#### Variables filtered by prefix

The variables are filtered by the prefix of their name, so several different ones (with the same prefix) can be defined for different hosts and will be filtered out completely.

E.g. the Inventory:

```ini
[my_servers]
myserver01 host_var_one=foo host_var_two=bar
myserver02 host_var_one=biz host_var_two=baz host_var_three=boz host_var_four=buz
myserver03 host_var_one=fizz host_var_two=buzz host_var_six=dazz
```

returns the following result:

```
TASK [Dict of host_vars] **********************************************
ok: [myserver01] => {
    "msg": {
        "myserver01": {
            "host_var_one": "foo",
            "host_var_two": "bar"
        },
        "myserver02": {
            "host_var_four": "buz",
            "host_var_one": "biz",
            "host_var_three": "boz",
            "host_var_two": "baz"
        },
        "myserver03": {
            "host_var_one": "fizz",
            "host_var_six": "dazz",
            "host_var_two": "buzz"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Out of all the fantastic answers I got to this question, this one is my favorite. I changed `map('selectattr', 'key', 'match', 'host_var_')` to `map('selectattr', 'key', 'in', ['var1', 'var2', ...])` so that I could list all the variables I'm interested in for inclusion. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 3):

The simplest solution is putting the below declarations into the *vars*

```yaml
selection: "{{ dict(ansible_play_hosts_all|
                    zip(hostvars|json_query(_query))) }}"
_query: '*.{host_var_one: host_var_one, host_var_two: host_var_two}'
```

Given the above inventory, the result is

```yaml
  selection:
    myserver01:
      host_var_one: foo
      host_var_two: bar
    myserver02:
      host_var_one: biz
      host_var_two: baz
    myserver03:
      host_var_one: fizz
      host_var_two: buzz
```

In the dictionary, all hosts keep the same variables selected by the common *_query*.

---

Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
- hosts: my_servers
  gather_facts: false

  vars:

    selection: "{{ dict(ansible_play_hosts_all|
                        zip(hostvars|json_query(_query))) }}"
    _query: '*.{host_var_one: host_var_one, host_var_two: host_var_two}'

  tasks:

    - debug:
        var: selection
      run_once: true
```

---

Q: ***"List the variables for each host in the inventory."***

A: For example, given the inventory

```yaml
shell> cat hosts
all:
  children:
    my_servers:
      hosts:
        myserver01:
          host_var_one: foo
          host_var_two: bar
          host_var_three: baz
          sel_vars: [host_var_one, host_var_two, host_var_three]
        myserver02:
          host_var_one: biz
          host_var_two: baz
          sel_vars: [host_var_one, host_var_two]
        myserver03:
          host_var_one: fiz
          host_var_two: buz
          sel_vars: [host_var_two]
```

The playbook below

```yaml
- hosts: my_servers
  gather_facts: false

  vars:

    sel_vals: "{{ sel_vars|map('extract', vars)|list }}"
    sel_dict: "{{ dict(sel_vars|zip(sel_vals)) }}"
    sel_all: "{{ ansible_play_hosts_all|map('extract', hostvars, 'sel_dict') }}"
    selection: "{{ dict(ansible_play_hosts_all|zip(sel_all)) }}"

  tasks:

    - set_fact:
        sel_dict: "{{ sel_dict }}"
    - debug:
        var: selection
      run_once: true
```

gives (abridged)

```yaml
  selection:
    myserver01:
      host_var_one: foo
      host_var_three: baz
      host_var_two: bar
    myserver02:
      host_var_one: biz
      host_var_two: baz
    myserver03:
      host_var_two: buz
```

The task *set_fact* is necessary to "instantiate" (create in *hostvars*) the variables *sel_dict* for all hosts.

You can select the variables dynamically. For example, put the below declaration into the *vars*

```yaml
    sel_vars: "{{ query('varnames', '.*_one') }}"
```

The result will be

```yaml
  selection:
    myserver01:
      host_var_one: foo
    myserver02:
      host_var_one: biz
    myserver03:
      host_var_one: fiz
```

Answer (score 2):

I always enjoy seeing the competing ways of solving these problems, but here's mine: because [`json_query`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/6/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#selecting-json-data-json-queries) is rotten at dealing with top-level dicts, a little sprinkling of [`dict2items`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/6/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#transforming-dictionaries-into-lists) rotates it into an array of dicts which JMESPath is much better at dealing with, project the items into the same `[{key: .key, value: ...}]` shape for the things you want, then rotate it back into a dict with the opposite filter (`items2dict`)

```yaml
  - debug:
      msg: '{{ hostvars | dict2items | json_query(jq) | items2dict }}'
    delegate_to: localhost
    run_once: true
    vars:
      jq: '[*].{key: key, value: {one: value.host_var_one, two: value.host_var_two}}'
```

produces

```
ok: [alpha -> localhost] => {
    "msg": {
        "alpha": {
            "one": "a1",
            "two": "a2"
        },
        "beta": {
            "one": "b1",
            "two": "b2"
        }
    }
}
```

*I didn't follow what you were doing with the `zip` but to the best of my knowledge `hostvars` contains **all** hostvars, and thus no `zip` trickery required*

---

Or, if you have either a huge list, or an unknown list, of those hostvars to extract, I gravely lament the lack of dict comprehensions in ansible's Jinja2 but the iterative version *works* just fine:

```yaml
  - debug:
      msg: >-
        {%- set r = {} -%}
        {%- for hv in hostvars.keys()  -%}
        {%-   set d = {} -%}
        {%-   for f in the_facts -%}
        {%-     set _ = d.update({f: hostvars[hv][f]}) -%}
        {%-   endfor -%}
        {%-   set _ = r.update({hv: d}) -%}
        {%- endfor -%}
        {{ r }}
    vars:
      the_facts:
      - host_var_one
      - host_var_two
```